# Convolutional Neural Network always predicts the same class

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, classification, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a CNN that combines both a 3D brain image and its corresponding test score to predict which category the image will fall into. However, the CNN program always predict the same class when I run it and am not sure what other methods I can do to prevent this. I have searched up this problem with many plausible solution, but they did not work

So far, I have tried:

- Decreasing the learning rate
- Normalize the data to [0, 1]
- Change optimizers
- Change last layer's activation (softmax, sigmoid) and I only use categorical_crossentropy
- Add/remove dropout layers
- Changed into a simpler CNN model (to no avail)
- Balance the dataset

Please note that the amount of images I am using is a total of 20 3D brain images (5 per category) and that I cannot increase the sample size since there are simply not enough images.

I have also done this similar CNN model with solely images and the prediction is slightly better, although still bad. For example, the only-image CNN predicts almost every image into the same class with a few being different classes while the image+test CNN predicts only the same class every time.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
    import os
    import csv
    import tensorflow as tf  # 2.0
    import nibabel as nib
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder
    from keras.models import Model
    from keras.layers import Conv3D, MaxPooling3D, Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten 
    from keras.layers import Input, concatenate
    from keras import optimizers
    from keras.utils import to_categorical
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    # Administrative items
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
    
    # Where the file is located
    path = r'C:\Users\jesse\OneDrive\Desktop\Research\PD\decline'
    folder = os.listdir(path)
    
    
    # creating x - converting images to array
    def read_image(path, folder):
        list = []
        for i in range(len(folder)):
            files = os.listdir(path + '\\' + folder[i])
            for j in range(len(files)):
                image = np.array(nib.load(path + '\\' + folder[i] + '\\' + files[j]).get_fdata())
                image = np.resize(image, (96, 96, 96))
                image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=3)
                image /= 255.
                list.append(image)
        return list
    
    # creating y - one hot encoder
    def create_y():
        excel_file = r'C:\Users\jesse\OneDrive\Desktop\Research\PD\decline_label.xlsx'
        excel_read = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
        excel_array = np.array(excel_read['Label'])
        label = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(excel_array)
        label = label.reshape(len(label), 1)
        onehot = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False).fit_transform(label)
        return onehot
    
    # Splitting image train/test
    x = np.asarray(read_image(path, folder))
    y = np.asarray(create_y())
    test_size = .2
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=test_size)
    print(x_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
    
    
    # test scores
    tmtA = [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
    x_tmtA = np.asarray(tmtA)
    x_tmtA = np.resize(x_tmtA, (len(tmtA), 1))
    x_tmtA = np.expand_dims(x_tmtA, axis=2)
    x_train_tmtA, x_test_tmtA, y_train_tmtA, y_test_tmtA = train_test_split(x_tmtA, y_tmtA, test_size=test_size)
    
    
    
    batch_size = 4
    num_subjects = len(x)
    num_classes = len(folder)
    
    # image model
    inputs = Input((x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], x_train.shape[3], 1))
    conv1 = Conv3D(32, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv3D(32, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(conv1)
    drop1 = Dropout(0.5)(pool1)
    
    conv2 = Conv3D(64, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu')(drop1)
    conv2 = Conv3D(64, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(conv2)
    drop2 = Dropout(0.5)(pool2)
    
    conv3 = Conv3D(128, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu')(drop2)
    conv3 = Conv3D(128, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(conv3)
    drop3 = Dropout(0.5)(pool3)
    
    conv4 = Conv3D(256, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu')(drop3)
    conv4 = Conv3D(256, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(pool4)
    
    conv5 = Conv3D(256, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu')(drop4)
    conv5 = Conv3D(256, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu')(conv5)
    pool5 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(pool5)
    
    flat1 = Flatten()(drop5)
    dense1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(flat1)
    dense2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(dense1)
    dense3 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(dense2)
    drop6 = Dropout(0.5)(dense3)
    dense4 = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(drop6)
    
    model_image = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=dense4)
    
    
    # tmtA model
    input_tmtA = Input((1, 1))
    flat_tmtA1 = Flatten()(input_tmtA)
    dense_tmtA1 = Dense(num_subjects, activation='relu')(flat_tmtA1)
    dense_tmtA2 = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(dense_tmtA1)
    
    model_tmtA = Model(inputs=input_tmtA, outputs=dense_tmtA1)
    
    combine1 = concatenate([model_image.output, model_tmtA.output])
    dense_combine1 = Dense(num_subjects, activation='relu')(combine1)
    dense_combine2 = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(dense_combine1)
    
    
    # final model
    model = Model(inputs=[model_image.input, model_tmtA.input], outputs=[dense_combine2])
    
    opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-9)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit([x_train, x_train_tmtA], y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=15, shuffle=True)
    score = model.evaluate([x_test, x_test_tmtA], y_test, batch_size=batch_size)
    print(score)
```

Comment: I have not worked with 3D images. But for 2D you can perform augmentation such as add noise or rotate the image - thereby increasing your dataset. You can maybe try something on similar lines to increase the dataset. 5 images per category might not be enough for a NN to learn the features.

Comment: That is a great suggestion that I have not tried. I have briefly heard about this but have never implemented this method yet. I will look it up and see how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: [This](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-configure-image-data-augmentation-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/) might help you